# How to get sections of biblatex bibliography on the same page in a report and as sections in TOC?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning, report

I am using documentclass `report` and I would like to achieve the following arrangement for the Bibliography with biblatex, but after a long day of frustration with it I don't quite know how to do it:

1) I have split my Bibliography in two parts, "Books on Things" and "Everything Else", and would like to have an unnumbered TOC entry called "Bibliography" with unnumbered subentries called "Books on Things" and "Everything Else", respectively. I can only get both Bibliography parts to be unnumbered chapters in TOC, rather than sections of a chapter called Bibliography.

2) When I print the `bibheading` and both bibliographies, each of the three is printed on its own page rather than on one page, even though they would fit. It appears this has to do with using `\documentclass{report}`. Is there any way to get all three on the same page (no pun intended)?

Here is a minimal code (hopefully I haven't forgotten anything):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=alphabetic,
bibstyle=alphabetic,
sorting=anyvt,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\pretocmd{\section}{\ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi}{}{} % puts sections on new page except 1st one

\usepackage[
bookmarksopen,
bookmarksnumbered,
colorlinks=false,
urlcolor=blue,
linkcolor=red,
citecolor=green,
frenchlinks=false
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[chapter]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents

\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[
 heading=bibintoc,
 keyword={books on things},
 title={Books on Things}
 ]       
\printbibliography[
 heading=bibintoc,
 notkeyword={books on things},
 title={Everything Else}
 ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `heading=subbibintoc` in your `\printbibliography`s.

Comment: @gusbrs: yes, indeed, but when I use `subbibintoc`, both bibliography parts get assigned to the last (numbered) chapter. Should I simply create a separate unnumbered chapter called 'Bibliography' because of that? It seemed like a crude way to accomplish something that biblatex most likely can do on its own, but I am too ignorant as to how to.

Comment: Your `\printbibheading` should provide your "unnumbered chapter". I'm not sure why your `\printbibliography`s would be assigned to the previous numbered chapter. Technically, you could always go with `heading=none` and do headings on your own, but it would be less than ideal imho.

Comment: @gusbrs: `\printbibheading` does not seem to produce any entry in my TOC. Is the default `\bibheading` supposed to produce a TOC entry?

Comment: Ah, there we go! Use `\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]`.

Comment: @gusbrs: Nice catch! I knew I was missing something! Thank you so much for looking into it! 

By any chance do you happen to know any workaround for the second issue?

Comment: I believe both my suggestions combined solve both issues, please try with the code provided in the answer.

Comment: @gusbrs: you are entirely correct, they do. What's still causing the second problem is the line `\pretocmd{\section}{\ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi}{}{}`, which I use to put the numbered sections on a new page. Do you think there is a way for the Bibliography to "escape" this?

Comment: As far as I know, behind the scenes, the heading is printed by biblatex using the regular sectioning commands. So, my answer to that is "probably no". But I would advise you against this tampering, anyway. It is hardly usual to start a new page at every section.

Comment: @gusbrs: my problem is that my sections are more similar to chapters as it is a somewhat big project connecting very different things. I am hoping that line of code could be modified so as to exclude the Bibliography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually almost there. As the `report` class offers the `chapter` level, calls for calls for `\printbibliography` and `\printbibheading` will be placed at this level, the same is true for the option `heading=bibintoc`. To get your `\printbibliography`s at `section` level, you should use `heading=subbibintoc`. And, finally, you get your `\printbibheadint` in the TOC, you need the option `heading=bibintoc`.

So, with:

```
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[
 heading=subbibintoc,
 keyword={books on things},
 title={Books on Things}
 ]       
\printbibliography[
 heading=subbibintoc,
 notkeyword={books on things},
 title={Everything Else}
 ]
```

You should be fine.