# Is it possible to have each section on a new page except for sections of the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, sectioning

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450297/how-to-get-sections-of-biblatex-bibliography-on-the-same-page-in-a-report-and-as). I have the following line of code in my preamble

```
\pretocmd{\section}{\ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi}{}{}
```

which puts each section on a new page except for the very first section of a chapter. My problem is that if I use something like

```
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[
 heading=bibintoc,
 keyword={books on things},
 title={Books on Things}
 ]       
\printbibliography[
 heading=bibintoc,
 notkeyword={books on things},
 title={Everything Else}
 ]
```

in the document body, then the bibliography title and the bibliography sections are also placed on 3 different pages, whereas I want them to stay together. My question is thus

> Is there a way to modify the aforementioned code of line in such a way that it does not apply to the bibliography (or some such workaround)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in your preamble:

```
\newif\ifinbib
\pretocmd{\section}{\ifinbib\else\ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi\fi}{}{}
\pretocmd{\printbibheading}{\inbibtrue}{}{}
```

It provides a new conditional `\ifinbib` (false by default) which is set to true as soon as you `\printbibheading`. After this, the conditional for `\clearpage` is never called.